# Generic structure of Intel C++ Compiler itself

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, intel

I want to learn, how Intel C++ Compiler works. I want to find a diagramm, which will show the internal structure of Intel compiler for X86 and X86_64 with major parts of it drawn. Parts I want are "Code generation", "Front-end", "Back-end", register allocation, analysises, etc.

I was able only to find a picture for Itanium compiler here download.intel.com/technology/itj/q41999/pdf/compiler.pdf. This picture is good, but x86 compiler can't have a "Predication" part as it have no predicate registers, ...

Question: Where can I find a image or description of structure if Intel C++ Compiler for x86

[image: IA-64 Intel compiler structure]

Comment: Constantin, Where can I find a image or description of structure if Intel C++ Compiler for x86

Comment: why don't you ask intel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try hunting around intel's website using google with the following search criteria:

```
site:intel.com +compiler +design
site:intel.com filetype:pdf +compiler +design
```

I came across:

- [An Overview of the Intel® IA-64
  Compiler](http://download.intel.com/technology/itj/q41999/pdf/compiler.pdf)
- [The Making of a Compiler for the
  Intel® ItaniumTM Processor](ftp://download.intel.com/technology/itj/q32001/pdf/art_4.pdf)

Which I think might help...

update by osgx: also some lections from intel in russian: http://www.i-lab.nsu.ru/special_courses_old/modern_optimizing_compilers/

Comment: thanks, but "An overview.." already is in the question and this image is from it. Also, it is about itanium, not x86

Comment: Yes.. I missed the original reference... so sorry about the repeat!   I agree Information on the x86 compiler seems to be sparse.. the best I can find is a summary of features... http://www.nccs.nasa.gov/images/CompilerProfessional.pdf

Comment: probably the same front end but different back end for code gen

Comment: As the instruction set and registers are different this will also have a impact on the low level optimisations that can be achieved.. register tracking etc.. high level optimisations should be okay (code redundancy etc..)